# Angular Fire - Display Issue with Empty Data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am new to Firebase and Angular JS so please excuse any obvious "what the heck are you doing's"...

I have a few pages that are nested:

- A) Directory (templates/tab-directory.html)
- A.1) Specialty (templates/tab-specialty.html)
- A.1.1) Team (templates/tab-team.html)

My tab-specialty.html looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{specialty.name}}">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-subheader item-input-inset">
    <div class="button-bar">
    ...
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="has-subheader">
  ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This doesn't always display the data. I know I am doing something wrong with asynchronous calls or something along those lines because it seems like the data is just not 'ready' for me to display.

The `{{specialty.name}}` doesn't always display. If I do `ionic serve` on the specialty page, it will display fine. However, when I start from one level higher and click into that page, it will not.

My app.js has the following states in it:

```
  .state('tab.directory', {
    url: '/directory',
    views: {
      'tab-directory': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-directory.html',
        controller: 'DirectoryCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.specialty', {
    url: '/specialty/:specialtyId',
    views: {
      'tab-directory': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-specialty.html',
        controller: 'SpecialtyCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.team', {
    url: '/team/:teamId',
    views: {
      'tab-directory': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-team.html',
        controller: 'TeamCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

My controllers.js has the following controller for specialty:

```
...
.controller('SpecialtyCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Specialties, Staff, Teams){
    var specialtyId = $stateParams.specialtyId;

    ...

    Specialties.$loaded().then(function(array){
        var syncArray = array.getById(specialtyId);
        if(syncArray.length > 0){
            $scope.specialty = syncArray[0];
            console.log($scope.specialty);
        }
    });

    Staff.$loaded().then(function(array){
        var allArray = array.getBySpecialtyId(specialtyId);
        hasConsults = getHasConsults(allArray);

        if(hasConsults){
            // Default to consults if we have them
            $scope.isConsultsActive = true;
            $scope.staffList = allArray.filter(function(staff){
                return staff.is_consult;
            });
        } else {
            // If no consults, default to all
            $scope.isAllActive = true;
            $scope.staffList = allArray;
        }
    });

    // Watch for new/updated/removed staff for this specialty
    Staff.$watch(function(event){
        var allArray = Staff.getBySpecialtyId(specialtyId);
        hasConsults = getHasConsults(allArray);

        // Sort the lists
        allArray.sort(sortList);

        $scope.allStaff = allArray;
        if($scope.isConsultsActive){
            $scope.staffList = allArray.filter(function(staff){
                return staff.is_consult;
            });
        }
    });
...
```

And my services.js has the following services defined:

```
.service('Staff', function($firebaseArray, $window){

  var staffList = $firebaseArray.$extend({
  ...
  });

  var ref = new $window.Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("staff");
  var syncArray = new staffList(ref);

  return syncArray;
})

.service('Teams', function($firebaseArray, $window){

  var staffList = $firebaseArray.$extend({
  ...
  });

  var ref = new $window.Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("teams");
  var syncArray = new staffList(ref);

  return syncArray;
})
```

The $scope.specialty is the object that doesn't always seem to get filled. I am having the same problem on the teams page as well, but the example is almost exactly the same as this.

Comment: Is all of this code necessary to demonstrate the question? I can't tell what's relevant here and what is superfluous to the problem set. Written like this, it's more like remote debugging than Q&A. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I believe it is necessary. All of the context that applies to the question is what I've supplied above: the template html, the services (data source), the controllers (how the data is being used), and the states (how the pages are connected). My apologies if it is too much or overwhelming but I wanted to supply whatever context was needed.

Comment: I think the problem is that a large amount of static code in a SO post rarely. helps. Could you create a CodePen that reproduces the issue? That would make it much easier to debug.